# Mathematica Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Mathematica t-shirt in your size
- Mathematica die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: mathematica.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: mathematica.stackexchange.com sticker]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: Could we have [a pentagon](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=5387958#5387958) in the inside?

Comment: @Verde Heptagons Eat Pentagons - They Are Great On New Swag

Comment: Great, thanks! Love @verde's subversive suggestion too.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this will totally be a cool geek clothing! However, I find it somewhat penny-pinching to receive only one T-shirt, when English Language & Usage [actually sent us **two**](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/mis-printed-english-se-t-shirts)… Just saying!

Comment: @F'x While I wouldn't be opposed to two t-shirts (possibly one with the pentagon), wasn't the reason they sent out two on [english.se] because of Jin's typo? At least, that's my impression from the meta post you linked to. As they say, _"Don't look a gift horse in the mouth"_... ;)

Comment: @R.M Shhh ... you could use the spare t-shirt [as a sail to get to the conference.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=PJvosb4UCLs#t=110s)

Comment: @R.M the first one was misprinted, yes (probably making it a somewhat rare SE collector's item)… that second part of my comment was very much in jest, I apologize if that wasn't apparent enough!

Comment: I saw the email just now, it's really a BIG surprise! Thanks!

Comment: Hawt! Now posessing a proper T-Shirt, this will also enable @Verde to get out and get some more fresh [air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmH3xCpOSW8) (although I do very much enjoy the diverse links) ;-p

Comment: Thanks for the gift. I hadn't expected this at all. I know I shouldn't look a gifted horse in the mouth but is there any chance of getting a woman's fitted t-shirt instead of a male version?

Comment: @Heike ... and with a `torn[MyHeptagon]` version ...

Comment: @belisarius as long as there isn't any trace of confetti (or Waldo/Wally for that matter)

Comment: Ha, dammit, 6 positions from page 2 :)

Comment: What about a wrist band with "What Would Stephen Do?" printed on it.

Comment: Mine just arrived here in Australia. I agree with Heike, they are very much cut for a man's body shape, but that probably works better for me than anything too fitted. It goes very nicely with some of my pyjamas.

Comment: Just received mine (London area). Thanks! It's great to get something back - usually the only thing you get from contributing to on-line forums and mailing lists is spam. As a non-expert user, I like the fact that the SE system rewards the askers of questions as well as the answerers.

Answer (score 16):

Fresh from the 2012 Tech Conf (there will be a small blog about that soon).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Edit: (by rcollyer)

From left to right: [Mark McClure](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36/mark-mcclure), [Murta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2266/murta), [rcollyer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer), [Arnoud](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/105/arnoud-buzing), [Brett](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69/brett-champion), Yves, 
[Michael Wijaya](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/281/michael-wijaya), [Daniel](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau)

Comment: So much for @MarkMcClure's four days in a row. He probably owes me a t-shirt.

Comment: Can you give a list of the names so we know who is who?

Comment: @halirutan done. Up to the names I remember ...

Comment: Yves: where's the blog post you promised?!? Slacker! :)

Comment: but THEN WHO WAS PHOTO???

Comment: @rm-rf if by that you mean "who took the photo?" a random passer-by, almost literally.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes. [This is the meme reference](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/then-who-was-phone)

Comment: Too bad I missed that. Next time, then.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin you can still send a picture of you and your t-shirt ;-)

Comment: @rm-rf the PHOTO WAS Mark Kotancheck FROM Evolved Analytics!!!

Comment: @rcollyer 's not slacking, 's lagging.

Comment: Here's an opportunity to test the `ImageCorrelate` example in the help system, using this instead of the Solvay conference photograph. It didn't work for me... :)

Comment: ...that's a handsome bunch we have there. :)

Comment: @J.M. and no photoshopping involved. Promise.

Comment: Heeey! I saw it just now!! Cool..

Answer (score 6):

Mine came in the mail today.  Anyone else?
Definitely nice that it's a week ahead of the user conference.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it got there in time. :)

Comment: Mark, are you gonna wear it too? The more the merrier...

Comment: @Yves Four straight days!

Comment: Done deal! Game´s on.

Comment: I Got mine, too! As the [proposer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica) I'll be getting two! So, (if the second arrives on time) I'll only have to where them two days at a time.

Comment: @rcollyer Hmm... I feel like you should get more than two t-shirts. See you there!

Comment: Their careers site sent me a great portfolio, so I'm not complaining.

Comment: @AnnaLear Can I get an e-mail to my another (e-mail) address ? I haven't used the former one for a few months (so it is blocked now) and therefore I've added recently my main e-mail.

Comment: @Artes I don't see any changes to your contact email, just your OpenID. You might want to update that as well. Drop me an email (the address is in my profile), and I'll set you up with some swag. :)